# PHP format for Lakh and Crore

Tags: php, codeigniter, number-formatting

Want to format number in php like `1,00,00,00,000`. I am trying the following function
`number_format($var['count'])`
but it is giving me following answer `1,000,000,000`

Thanks and Regards

Comment: That's an odd format - why don't you want commas separating thousands?

Comment: @andrewsi It's a fair assumption that this is a local specific format for India/Pakistan which uses Lakh (written as 1,00,000) and Crore (written as 1,00,00,000) for grouping large numbers.

Comment: as u see can the following number represents 10(ten crore,crore),00(ten lakh,lakh),00(ten thousand,thousand),000(hundred,tens,unit)

Comment: @Abizern - huh. I guess this is what I've learned today!

Comment: @Monkpit this what i was looking for thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this, to do additional formatting read through `PHP's` documentation: [PHP.NET - Money Format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

```
$dollar = 6000000000;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
echo $dollar = money_format('%!i', $dollar);
```

**Output:**
`6,00,00,00,000.00`

Comment: Great ..... Thumbs up

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$number = 123554646;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_IN");
echo money_format("The price is %i", $number);
```

**Output**

```
The price is INR 12,35,54,646.00
```

Check [Phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jwes-i3mn)

Comment: Is there really a reason to duplicate the answer that has already been given?

Comment: @Abizern but its not same output.

Comment: It's a slight difference in formatting, the crucial point of the answer - `setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_IN");` is the same.

Comment: @Abizern Help other or Just wait. Don't pull legs from behind

Comment: Vote for Php fiddle..

Comment: @Abdulla if you would like to mention something about how to format numbers in PHP, then it would be best mentioned as a comment on the existing answer. You should not duplicate the existing answer just to make a minor tweak.